# How to say 'scene' in a visual novel

Tags: words, english-to-japanese

When describing a scene, as in segment of a story, from a visual novel, can I use シーン? Or does シーン mean scene as in location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use シーン and 場面 interchangeably. Note that シーン in Japanese never refers to a geographical location; "return to the scene of the crime" is 犯行の現場に戻る, for example.